# redirect to another page instead of recieving Django standarf 404 error

Tags: django

i have something  like this in my views.py

```
    instance = get_object_or_404(register,pk=request.user.id)
```

Now if there is no related object against this user i receive i standard django 404 eror 
saying no matches found.
what i want here is instead of receiving this 404 error redirect it to another page say "something.html". but i dont know how. i am using method = "POST"
is there any way to redirect it to other page instead of receiving a 404 error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on what the Big Picture is, you might want to look at django.contrib.flatpages and see what they are doing. Basically they are dealing with the 404 in middleware and then looking at the path to decided if there is something they can return. I have used variations on this on a couple of sites.

Answer (score 5):

using a try/except block you can redirect if the object is not found

```
try:
    instance = register.get(pk=request.user.id)
except register.DoesNotExist:
    return HttpResponseRedirect('url that renders something.html')
```

FYI, definition of django `get_object_or_404` function looks like this

```
def get_object_or_404(klass, *args, **kwargs):
    """ 
    Uses get() to return an object, or raises a Http404 exception if the object
    does not exist.

    klass may be a Model, Manager, or QuerySet object. All other passed
    arguments and keyword arguments are used in the get() query.

    Note: Like with get(), an MultipleObjectsReturned will be raised if more than one
    object is found.
    """
    queryset = _get_queryset(klass)
    try:
        return queryset.get(*args, **kwargs)
    except queryset.model.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404('No %s matches the given query.' % queryset.model._meta.object_name)
```

from the [docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/views/#the-http404-exception), If you raise Http404 at any point in a view function, Django will catch it and return the standard error page for your application, along with an HTTP error code 404.

look at [customizing error views](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/views/#customizing-error-views) if you want to render a custom 404.html based on the context variables